# Should I make a new Class in Rails for Redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, redis

I'm starting to use Redis, and first thing my code is not too DRY, and was going to consolidate it in the application.rb and controller.  Is this the best way to go, or should I make a new Class called Redis, and have all the logic in there?

My models are currently Customers, Orders, Products, and I'm using a lot of counters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need a combination of new and existing model classes.

In many cases you can just drop the model used by the view directly into the datastore, which saves repetition. However, there will always be some places where the needs of the view and the datastore are different.

For example a property that appears as a list of values in the view may need to be stored as a separate set key rather than serialized with the other properties of the model.

Comment: Sorry - I used the wrong term and updated my original post.  What I meant was, should I make a new Class - "Redis" and have all the logic for updating the counts across all the models there, or should I use the application.rb and application controller?

Comment: That would depend on the complexity of your redis client. If it is just something like redis.incr(key) as a direct call to your redis library, you don't need a separate class. If you have something more complex like choosing a redis node to use or mapping parameters to key names you should create a separate class to keep the business logic part uncluttered.